# Relay bandwidth reporting frequency

Tags: relays, bandwidth

I've been running a middle relay on a Raspberry Pi for some time now. Recently, I switched out my first generation Pi for a 2nd generation model B. I installed Tor on the new Pi and moved the keys accordingly. The relay came up again just fine, and has been functioning without errors since.

There's one issue, though. On Globe and Atlas, the bandwidth charts for small time intervals remain empty. The longer intervals (i.e. 1 month and above) do show recent data, indicating that the relay *is* reporting data *sometimes*. It seems as if it's just not doing so often enough. For reference, the concerned relay is [E1AF83F60B55F4E53A573D4CCDA2C9A58FEC4ADD](https://globe.torproject.org/#/relay/E1AF83F60B55F4E53A573D4CCDA2C9A58FEC4ADD).

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer versions of Tor don't report data as accurately anymore, but globe hasn't been updated yet to deal with that. It's nothing to be concerned about.

The change was introduced in 0.2.5.11 with the following ChangeLog entry:

`o Minor bugfixes (statistics):
    - Increase period over which bandwidth observations are aggregated
      from 15 minutes to 4 hours. Fixes bug 13988; bugfix on 0.0.8pre1.`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is there a changelog entry somewhere that mentions this? I couldn't find anything at first glance..

Comment: Updated my answer, there you go :)